# Как изменить url swagger-а в spring?

Tags: java, spring, swagger

Нужно чтобы сваггер деплоился не в рут директорию http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html, а в отдельную папочку api-docs.
Устанавливаю проперти

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@PropertySource("classpath:swagger.properties")
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Файл свойств

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=api-docs
```

Но это ничего не меняет. Страница открывается по прежнему адресу.

Comment: Тебе нужно что бы url до сваггера был http://localhost:8080/api-docs/swagger-ui.html ?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать контроллер, который отдаёт по заданному url страницу со сваггером

```
@Controller
 public class SwaggerController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/api-docs/swagger-ui", method=GET)
    public String swaggerHtml(){
       return "redirect:swagger-ui.html";
    }
 }
```

Comment: На сколько я понял, это вроде ридеркта, а нужно сделать так, чтобы при доступе в рут директорию сваггер был недоступен. Такие требования безопасности.

Comment: К сожалению конфигурации для этого нет, в issues springfox [один человек говорил про monkey patching](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/977). Но мне кажется лучше тогда написать фильтр, который будет выкидывать ошибку при обращении к обычным swagger url'ам

Answer (score 0):

Как ответил @RuslanMasgutov не нашел способа изменить директорию по-умолчанию для сваггера. Решил проблему, прописав все пути используемые сваггером в конфигурацию спринг-секьюрити.

```
   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/v2/api-docs/**", 
                         "/configuration/ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**",
                         "/configuration/security/**", "/swagger-ui.html/**", 
                         "/swagger-ui.html#/**");
    }
```